# changing default program

Tags: gnome-terminal, bittorrent, transmission

I accidentally changed my torrent magnet link default file to terminal instead of transmission, and the remember this application check box is checked. So now i am stuck in opening up terminal whenever I click on a magnet link. How can I change the default application from terminal to transmission. please help I am new to ubuntu, so please make it simple to understand if it is via terminal.

Comment: Magnet links are mostly found in web pages and therefore handled by the web browser. Which web browser are you using? Firefox? Chromium?

Comment: i amusing firefox for web browsing

Comment: thank you very much actually i only wanted the know that it is handled by web browser. Very glad that everyone is so sharing in here. Thank you very much once again

Answer (score 0):

I think this is chromium based on `xdg-open`, so the solution would be:

**tell xdg-open to open magnet links using Transmission.**

In the terminal, type:

```
xdg-mime default transmission-gtk.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet
```

This can probably also be done in chromium settings, but I currently don't have access as I'm on mobile.

Comment: Firefox uses the same `xdg-open` mechanism unless it's overridden by an internal rule of Firefox, that you would have to set manually (or through some add-on).

Comment: Thanks for info. I don't use Firefox, but it is useful to know it also uses xdg-open.

Comment: It doesn't use `xdg-open` directly, but it follows the same specification and reads the same configuration files.

Comment: If answer fixed your problem can you please click the checkmark on answer to mark it as accepted. It will also establish credit for you on this site, as well let anyone else with issue know it a working solution.